# How do I set read consistency when executing Shark on DSE 4.5?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax

[This page](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkStart.html?scroll=sparkStart__spkShrkLaunch) hints that shark can be started using `-Dspark.cassandra.input.consistency.level=LOCAL_QUORUM` (referred to [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#configuration-options-for-adjusting-reads)) Java system properties, but I keep getting command line errors. Could anyone give an example on how I can start DSE Shark and run queries using `LOCAL_QUORUM` read consistence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-Dspark.cassandra.input.consistency.level=LOCAL_QUORUM is for Spark SQL which is not Shark.

set cassandra.consistency.level to your shark conf.

bin/dse shark  -hiveconf cassandra.consistency.level=LOCAL_QUORUM